# How to search for symbols within a VBA Makro for Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I´m new to **VBA** and have to write a little Makro for work.
This Makro will be used to search for a Special set of symbols inside a **Word Document**.

So far I found a way to search for a string and mark it. 
Yet it only functions with normal chars. The question is how to include symbols into the search.

My code so far is:

```
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "String"
    .Execute Forward:=True
End With
```

The symbol-string needed to be found inside the document is: [•]

Thank You for Your Suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something as easy as this works for me:

```
Public Sub Testme()

    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "•"
        .Execute Forward:=True
    End With

End Sub
```

If this is the bullet format and not a simple dot in a text, then you may use something like this to select the bulleted paragraph:

```
Sub FindBullet()
    Dim rngTarget As Word.Range
    Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph

    Set rngTarget = Selection.Range
    With rngTarget
        Call .Collapse(wdCollapseEnd)
        .End = ActiveDocument.Range.End

        For Each oPara In .Paragraphs
            If oPara.Range.ListFormat.ListType = _
               WdListType.wdListBullet Then
                oPara.Range.Select
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

[Source here](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008259_Finding_Formatted_Bulleted_Paragraphs.html).

Comment: Ok, that was trivial. And somehow exactly what I tried before. Just I didnt use a Public Sub and didnt manage to get the "•" into it, cause it would Change the Symbol. Thank You :)